# Get UUID from .mobileprovision File using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, shell, mobileprovision

I want to extract **UUID** from **.mobileprovision** file but unable to do that.

I tried *xml2js*, *provision* and diffrent modules of nodejs to achieve this and I also tried this https://gist.github.com/benvium/2568707 but did not get any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works just fine for me:

```
const provisioning = require('provisioning');

provisioning('XXX.mobileprovision', (err, obj) => {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle better
  console.log(obj.UUID);
});
```

Uses the [`provisioning`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/provisioning) module.

Comment: Thank you for the response i tried this but it throws this error         `Error: Command failed: Error reading S/MIME message
140160313910928:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:157:

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:637:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
`

Comment: @ZainAbbas I've ran it against various mobileprovision files I have and it works just fine for me, so I'm afraid I can't help you solve that error. Where is the file that you're trying to parse coming from?